# How to properly fix npm ERR! from permissions on Ubuntu on my path

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, jenkins, npm

**I ran**

```
npm install
```

from this path in my jenkins server:

```
ubuntu@IP:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/morningharwood$ npm install
```

It returned a big list of these same errors:

```
npm WARN engine karma@0.12.28: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.11.14","npm":"2.0.0"})
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.11.14/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.11.14/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.11.14
npm ERR! npm  v2.0.0
npm ERR! path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/morningharwood/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/morningharwood/node_modules'
...
```

I thought this is a permissions thing and I'm on ubuntu

```
sudo chown ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.nvm -Rv
```

**Problem:** I'm still getting the same errors

The owner remained the same.  I just got a list of these same messages with different paths.

```
ownership of ‘/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.11.14/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/stringstream/README.md’ retained as ubuntu
```

**Question:** How do I get `npm install to run properly`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `node install` without the `-g` option it will install to the `node_modules` directory in your working directory, which is

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/morningharwood
```

So look for your permissions problem in that directory, not in your `nvm` installation directory.

Comment: Ding! Thanks! First dive into dev ops and I'm trying something too advanced.  Only to get bogged down by a dummy mistake.  Gave up too easily for something so simple. Thanks again